# get next posts link with custom html anchor tag

Tags: wordpress

i want to use the `next_posts_link ()` Wordpress function to get the next page, it gives me an anchor tag i just want to add a class to this anchor tag.
i want to add to next page anchor tag the class `page-next` and previous page the class `old-page`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function for `next/previous_post_link();`

```
<?php
# get_adjacent_post( $in_same_cat = false, $excluded_categories = '', $previous = true )
$next_post_obj  = get_adjacent_post( '', '', false );
$next_post_ID   = isset( $next_post_obj->ID ) ? $next_post_obj->ID : '';
$next_post_link     = get_permalink( $next_post_ID );
$next_post_title    = '&raquo;'; // equals "»"
?>
<a href="<?php echo $next_post_link; ?>" rel="next" class="pagination pagination-link pagination-next">
    <?php echo $next_post_title; ?>
</a>
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: thank you from replying, but i'm looking for next post link or next page link not only single post link.

Comment: Then you need WordPress pagination for next page.. In this case, post link will not work

Comment: what function should i use ?

Comment: I am not able to send the code example bcoz I am outside somewhere. Will let u know later but you can refer this link for now https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple solution. Just use this code to show your links in a tag.

```
<?php
global $paged;

    if ( get_previous_posts_link() ) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_pagenum_link( $paged - 1 ); ?>">Prev</a><?php
    }    
    if ( get_next_posts_link() ) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_pagenum_link( $paged +1 ); ?>">Next</a><?php
    }    
?>
```